# RSelenium Browser not Opening

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm running an RSelenium browser in R. I had code written for it that was working completely fine until I tried to run it yesterday. Now, when I try to start a browser with `rd = rsDriver()`, I get the following message:

```
>checking Selenium Server versions:
> 
> BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
> 
> BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
> 
> BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
> 
> checking chromedriver versions:
> 
> BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
> 
> BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
> 
> BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
> 
> checking geckodriver versions:
> 
> BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
> 
> BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
> 
> BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
> 
> checking phantomjs versions:
> 
> BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
> 
> BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
> 
> BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
> 
> [1] "Connecting to remote server"
> 
> Could not open chrome browser.
> 
> Client error message:
> 
> Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to
> localhost port 4567: Connection refused
> 
> Check server log for further details.
> 
> $client
> 
> [1] "No sessionInfo. Client browser is mostly likely not opened."
> 
> $server
> 
> Process Handle command   : C:\Users\Jeffrey
> Jones\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpszSD5f\file2958371c4c79.bat 
> 
> system id : 14508
> 
> state     : exited
> 
> Warning message:
> 
> In rsDriver() : Could not determine server status.
>
```

And then nothing else works. I don't understand because the code was working fine 2 days ago. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: RSelenium is working OK for me, although I did just have to manually allow firewall access after a Java update on my system earlier today (Win10).  If you are running from a batch file, that might trip it up.

Comment: I gave RStudio firewall access, and I'm still receiving the same error. I have tried using all of the browsers. Could it be the port that I am using (4567)?

Comment: Might be worth a try. I usually use port 4444. I think it is Java that needs firewall access rather than RStudio - it worked OK once I had run my batch script manually and accepted all the firewall warnings.