# How to connect to a Selenium server through RSelenium?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, server, connection, rselenium

I'm trying to learn how to use the `RSelenium` package, but I haven't even been able to **connect to a server** yet. My code is as simple as:

```
library(RSelenium)
rs_driver <- rsDriver()
rs_driver
```

The error message I get is:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
$client
[1] "No sessionInfo. Client browser is mostly likely not opened."

$server
PROCESS 'file413018516402.bat', finished.
Warning message:
In rsDriver() : Could not determine server status.
```

I already tried:

1. Updating Java, Chrome, RStudio, and both `netstat` and `RSelenium`.
2. Several different specifications for `rsDriver()` arguments, varying:

   - The `browser`. For Chrome, I also tried different versions, varying `chromever`.
   - Setting `port` manually, or by using `free_port()` from `netstat`.
3. Turning off the Windows Defender Firewall for RStudio (though I'm not completely sure if that's necessary and if I did this properly).

Despite having come across some related questions (as listed below), either they remain unsolved or the suggested solutions weren't successfully implemented by me.

- [RSelenium browser not opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299070/rselenium-browser-not-opening)
- [Can't use RSelenium package, function rsDriver() says can't connect to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961465/cant-use-rselenium-package-function-rsdriver-says-cant-connect-to-browser)
- [RSelenium won't connect to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988475/rselenium-wont-connect-to-remote-server)

I'd really appreciate any help   :)

Comment: what your `rs_driver$server$log()` is returning?

Comment: The output is exactly:

```$stderr
[1] "Error: Could not find or load main class c(-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\"C:\\\\Users\\\\VITOR\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\binman\\\\binman_chromedriver\\\\win32\\\\111.0.5563.64.chromedriver.exe\","    
[2] "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: c(-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\"C:\\\\Users\\\\VITOR\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\binman\\\\binman_chromedriver\\\\win32\\\\111.0.5563.64.chromedriver.exe\","

$stdout
character(0)```

Comment: Go to "C:\Users\VITOR\AppData\Local\binman\binman_chromedriver\win32\111.0.5563.64", delete "LICENSE.chromedriver" and try again. It is a known [bug](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/263#issuecomment-1344014508) of wdman perhaps already solved in newer versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting "LICENSE.chromedriver" ([Ric Villalba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6912817/ric-villalba)'s suggestion) solved my problem.